# A continuous function $f$ such that $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}$ does not exists but $ \frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x\partial y}$ exists

Tags: real-analysis

Does there exist a continuous function $f:\mathbb R^2\to \mathbb R$ such that $\displaystyle \frac{\partial f}{\partial x}$ **does not exists** but $\displaystyle \frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x\partial y}$ exists.

I think yes. But I am unable to find an example of such function. Can anyone help me ?

Comment: Isn't $f_{xy}$ *defined* in terms of $f_x$?

Comment: @ Martin R ) No.$f_{xy}=\frac{\partial}{\partial x}(\frac{\partial f}{\partial y})$

Comment: @Panja717 Not really I just checked the definition and it is $f_{xy}=\frac{\partial}{\partial y}(\frac{\partial f}{\partial x})$ according to here http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/CalcIII/HighOrderPartialDerivs.aspx

Comment: @MartinR it seems the confusion is simply in the notation here. I was taught that $f_{xy}$ was differentiation with respect to $y$, then to $x$, and it looks like this is the notation used by OP and one of the users who answered as well

Comment: @Panja717 sorry a good question isn't getting good answers due to confusion in notation, when it's pretty clear what you meant.

Comment: @  mathers101) Please see my edited question..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let $f$ only depend on $x$, being continuous but not differentiable. Then $f_y=0$, hence $f_{xy}=0$. (Assuming that this means first differentiating with respect to $y$)

Comment: and $f_{yx}\not=f_{xy}$ in general

Answer (score 1):

The function $f: R^2 \to R$ where $f(x, y) = |x|+xy$ is an example

See that for the following function $$f_{yx} = 1$$ for every $(x, y) \ \epsilon \ R^2$

But $f_x$ doesn't exist at the following set of points $\{ (0, y) \ \epsilon \ R^2 \ | \ y \ \epsilon \ R \} $

Thus for the set $\{ (0, y) \ \epsilon \ R^2 \ | \ y \ \epsilon \ R \} \subset R^2$, $f_{yx}$ exists but $f_x$ doesn't exist

Comment: Whats the point of that summand $xy$? Beauty in mathematics is also about giving "canonical counterexamples". Just leave that summand and take $f(x,y)=|x|$ only.

Comment: I only wanted a scalar field which is such that $f_{yx} \ne 0$. I taught taking a scalar field for which $f_{yx} = 0$ might create confusion.

Comment: In fact I wanted a scalar field which is not independent of y.

Answer (score 0):

See this [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weierstrass_function) on the Weierstrass function $W_{\alpha}(x)$. It is continuous everywhere, but differentiable nowhere. So let
$$f(x,y)=W_{\alpha}(x)$$
Then $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}$ does not exist anywhere, and since $\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}=0$ the mixed derivative $\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x\partial y}$ exists everywhere (and is also equal to 0).